# Magento 1.7 "Invalid Shipping Method"

Tags: magento, web, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I'm hoping that someone here has come across this error before. I can't be any more specific than I'm going to be because I don't know exactly which bit of code is causing this error.

On http://www.gomediadev.co.uk/mycheapsupermarket/ - when trying to check out with ANY shipping method (currently set to free shipping) you receive the error "Invalid Shipping Method". I've even resorted to doing a global 'Find' for the term 'Invalid Shipping Method' and commented out any instances, however the error still persists. I'm coming to a bit of a brick wall now and was hoping someone may be able to shed a bit of light on this.

Many thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: Did you check the logfiles?

Comment: Hi Andre, yes I checked the log files and it doesn't show an error. This is why it's so strange! Have you any ideas on what may be causing it or experienced this before?

Comment: Hey Tom, if you can't get any hints from the system, i would start to debug the code to see what happens under the hood.

Comment: Hi Andre, where would you suggest I start with this? I've sort of gone full circle with this and seem to be back where I started. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated :)

Comment: Hey Andre, I was just wondering if you'd had any thoughts? :)

Comment: Check the block class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available and the template available.phtml

Comment: Hi Andre, I've looked at this but can't seem to pinpoint anything. I was wondering if you may be able to have a look at this for me? It's starting to drive me nuts now! :(

Comment: Could you please write me an email: andre.schubert78@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was, that there were 2 templates, both containing a form with the same id.
So on submitting the shipping method form, magento took the values of the other form with the same id.